# ¿Se puede usar "recursivo" en lugar de "recurrente"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sinónimos, adjetivos

Recientemente en la pregunta de meta [Necesitamos una pregunta canónica sobre ser/estar](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/necesitamos-una-pregunta-can%C3%B3nica-sobre-ser-estar) he usado la palabra "recurrente" para decir que las preguntas sobre este tema son algo recurrente.

> **[recurrente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VXdBgGD)**
>
> Del ant. part. act. de *recurrir*; lat. *recurrens, -entis*.
>
> 1. adj. Que recurre.
> 2. adj. Que vuelve a ocurrir o a aparecer, especialmente después de un intervalo.

Sin embargo, estuve a punto de usar "recursivo". Por mi condición de informático, tiendo a pensar en *recursivo* como algo que se llama a sí mismo (por aquello del código recursivo). Así que pensé que me iba a equivocar de adjetivo y puse "recurrente". Sin embargo, veo en la definición de "recursivo" lo siguiente:

> **[recursivo, va](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VXkDTwd)**
>
> Del lat. *recursus*, part. pas. de *recurrĕre* 'recurrir', e *-ivo*.
>
> 1. adj. Sujeto a reglas o pautas recurrentes.

Aparte de que ambas palabras tienen la misma raíz, esta primera acepción de "recursivo" me deja más dudas que claros. Si fuesen equivalentes, en el diccionario aparecería una acepción tal que así:

> 1. *adj. **recurrente** (‖ que vuelve a ocurrir o aparecer).*

Así que pregunto: **¿se puede usar "recursivo" para expresar lo mismo que "recurrente" en el sentido de algo que se repite cada cierto tiempo?**

Como añadido, en el mapa de diccionarios no aparece la voz "recursivo", por lo que debe de ser reciente, y [en Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recurrente%2Crecursivo&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecurrente%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Crecursivo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brecursivo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRecursivo%3B%2Cc0) las apariciones de "recursivo" son muy escasas en comparación con las de "recurrente". Las pocas veces que aparece son en textos científicos o en frases como

> El nuevo ministro [...] era sujeto de mucho empuje, muy **recursivo** y muy progresista.

o

> Harry Fltzgerald, un viejo irlandés, veterano y **recursivo**, cuya cascada voz...

Es decir, parece que "recursivo" tiene un significado aplicado a personas, que sería algo así como "provisto de recursos", y que no aparece recogido en el DRAE. En Ngram también he visto que la primera aparición de la palabra es sobre principios del siglo XX.

Comment: A juzgar por las definiciones, en lo _recursivo_ lo que se repite son las reglas. No tengo más argumentos técnicos, pero en mi vida (que incluye algo de programación e ingeniería) _recursivo_ tiene un ámbito bien específico y jamás lo consideraría sinónimo de _recurrente_. Tiene que ver con definiciones (casi) circulares de series numéricas, o procedimientos/funciones que se llaman/invocan a sí mismas.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo con @Rafael Aunque las definiciones parecen casi similares para mi recurrente es algo que vuelve a ocurrir de la misma manera una y otra vez mientras que recursivo es algo que ocurre otra vez pero que usa información/hechos de la iteración/ocurrencia anterior bajo las misma reglas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El `recursivo` aplicado a personas o lugares es un colombianismo:

> [**recursivo, a**](http://www.academiacolombianadelalengua.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/BREVE-DICCIONARIO-PDF-FINAL-JUNIO-7-DE-20131.pdf)
> *adj. coloq.* Dicho de una persona,
> que se le ocurren ideas para salir airosa en
> cualquier situación.
> **2.** Dicho de un lugar o sector de la ciudad, que tiene establecimientos  comerciales,  colegios,  facilidades de transporte. *El centro es muy recursivo.*
>
> <sup>*Breve Diccionario de Colombianismos*</sup>

La otra definición es la técnica, la que se refiere a ciertos procesos o funciones dentro de disciplinas específicas, y que, en mi opinión, el DRAE trató de generalizar, no muy felizmente, con esa críptica primera definición.

Por contraste, el *Larousse* no se aventura a insinuar que la palabra tiene uso general fuera de estas disciplinas:

> [**recursivo, a**](http://www.diccionarios.com/detalle.php?palabra=recursivo&dicc_100=on&Buscar.x=63&Buscar.y=22&dicc_100=on&dicc_52=on&dicc_95=on&dicc_58=on&dicc_94=on&dicc_96=on&palabra2=)
> **1** *adj.*  LINGÜÍSTICA  Se refiere al elemento lingüístico susceptible de ser incluido como constituyente de un elemento de la misma naturaleza un número indefinido de veces, en la gramática generativa.
> **2** INFORMÁTICA  Se aplica al programa organizado de modo que puede llamarse a sí mismo en el curso de su desarrollo.
>
> <sup>© Larousse Editorial, 2016</sup>

(Como agregado, no figura en estos diccionarios, pero creo que en matemática se dice cada vez más *función recursiva* en vez de *función recurrente*.)

Por todo lo anterior, a la pregunta

> ¿se puede usar "recursivo" para expresar lo mismo que "recurrente" en el sentido de algo que se repite cada cierto tiempo?

debe responderse que **no**. El significado de “recursivo”, o no tiene nada que ver con repeticiones (el colombianismo), o se usa de manera especializada dentro de ciertas disciplinas. No es un sinónimo de “recurrente”.

Answer (score 1):

Yo como español lo entiendo pero considero que podrías emplear otra palabra que considero más simple:

**repetitivo,va**

Desconozco si intentas emplear palabras quizás más cultas que otras más simples por alguna razón pero en principio en la mayoría de contextos puedes utilizar "recursivo" para expresar los mismo que "recurrente".

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta, y bienvenido a [spanish.se]! No es una cuestión de querer usar una palabra u otra, por más o menos culta que sea. Es una mera curiosidad por comprender los entresijos del español. :-)